# What is causing my site to de-index and be uncrawlable?

Tags: indexing, opencart, user-agent, robots.txt

I'm working on the site buydirectonline.com.au, which used to be crawled with no issues. All major search engines had it indexed and screaming frog could crawl the site with no issues.

However, all of a sudden, screaming frog is returning a 403 error, and the site is being de-indexed on all major search engines.

I've checked the obvious:
- robots.txt 
- search console messages/issues
- htaccess file

Nothing seems to have changed, everything seems to be how it was when the site was crawling properly.

Does anyone have any ideas on what i should try/investigate next?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is "stack" overflow, not "seo" overflow. I suggest you ask this question in an SEO forum.

Comment: Buzz off Paul, this is a completely valid question for stack overflow. Go get your internet points somewhere else.

Comment: Well you haven't given much info but 403 means forbidden, so Google and Screaming Frog must be blocked, perhaps by your .htaccess file, perhaps by your web host.

Comment: did you check `Google Webmasters` see if there is any error being shown there, if crawler is getting any error while crawling it will be shown there.